# Windows Authentication using Blazor with .Net Core WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, blazor

I have the task to develop a Blazor Webassembly App. This app is only used within the companys network and for security reasons we would like to use the existing AD and NTLM Authentication.

So far I have a minimal Blazor App configured and running in IIS. Its configured to use Windows Authentication and that works so far. When I open the app in Browser I get asked for my credentials.
The app should also communicate with a .net core webapi which is also secured by windows authentication. This webapi security too works as it should. When I open an URL to it in Browser I get asked for my credentials and the page loads as it should.

Now the Problem: When I call the same url (that works in Browser) from my Blazor app with HttpClient.GetAsync I get an "401: Not Authorized" error. Even though the app itself is loaded with the same authentication. Is there something I have to do?
The MSDN Documenations a gigantic and I couldnt find a Solution.

In the WebApi Startup.cs in ConfigureServices() I added

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthorization();
```

and in Configure()

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials());
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

PS:
The Blazor App uses .NET Core 3.1
The WebApi uese .NET 5.0

Comment: Is there an authentication header in the request?

Comment: According to Firefox there is nothing within the header that looks anything like authentication. That helps. But how do I get it there the (correct?) way?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking [Blazor WebAssembly additional security scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (all the examples are there)

To authorize your request, you can use HttpClient with BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com/base"))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler will automatically add Authorize header to all outgoing requests.

Note: This works only with Blazor Wasm, not Server.

Comment: I have upgraded the Blazor WASM Project to 5.0. Now I can use AddHttpClient as you decribed it. But when I try to to get HttpClient from IHttpClientFactory I injected in my Page I get the following error "No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered."

Comment: When I add 
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
the error is gone. But the Http Header still does not have any authentication information. Could it be because the WebApi is not on the same base address as the WASM?